# CakePHP 3: Migration doesn't save update data

Tags: postgresql, cakephp, cakephp-3.0, database-migration

**Environment:**
CakePHP 3
Postgres

I'm trying to do a migration to add a new field, then *update* some data for that field in our Postgres database. The entity seems to indicate that it's updated, but when I view the database, it is not saved.

**Code**

```
<?php
use Cake\Cache\Cache;
use Cake\ORM\TableRegistry;
use Migrations\AbstractMigration;

class AddDisplayRouteNumberToAgencies extends AbstractMigration
{
    /**
     * Up Method.
     */
    public function up()
    {
        $table = $this->table('agencies');
        $table->addColumn('display_route_number', 'boolean', [
            'default' => true,
            'null' => false,
        ]);
        $table->update();

        // Try to clear the Model cache
        Cache::clear(null, '_cake_model_');

        $patchData = [
            'display_route_number' => false
        ];

        $agencies = TableRegistry::get('Agencies');

        $agency = $agencies->get(25);
        // And save it back to the DB
        $agencies->patchEntity($agency, $patchData);
debug($agency);
        // Added after comment from ndm
        $agencies->save($agency);
    }

    /**
     * Down method
     */
    public function down()
    {
        $table = $this->table('agencies');
        $table->removeColumn('display_route_number');
        $table->update();

        // Clear the CakePHP Model cache
        Cache::clear(null, '_cake_model_');
    }
}
```

**Results from `debug()`**

```
object(App\Model\Entity\Agency) {
    'id' => (int) 25,
    'full_name' => 'Agency',
    'legacy_agency_slug' => null,
    'created' => object(Cake\I18n\Time) {

        'time' => '2015-11-19T10:58:51+0000',
        'timezone' => 'UTC',
        'fixedNowTime' => false

    },
    'modified' => object(Cake\I18n\Time) {

        'time' => '2015-11-19T10:58:51+0000',
        'timezone' => 'UTC',
        'fixedNowTime' => false

    },
    'display_route_number' => false,
    '[new]' => false,
    '[accessible]' => [
        '*' => true
    ],
    '[dirty]' => [
        'display_route_number' => true
    ],
    '[original]' => [],
    '[virtual]' => [],
    '[errors]' => [],
    '[repository]' => 'Agencies'
}
```

**Postgres query and results**

```
SELECT id, display_route_number
FROM agencies
WHERE id = 25;

 id | display_route_number 
----+----------------------
 25 | t
(1 row)
```

### Other attempts

I also tried just using `save()` rather than `patchEntities()`, which returned the same results, except `[dirty]` is empty.

```
    $agencies = TableRegistry::get('Agencies');
    $agency = $agencies->get(25);
    // Items to update
    $agency->display_route_number = false;
    // And save it back to the DB
    $agencies->save($agency);
```

Comment: FYI, `patchEntity()` won't save anything, only `Table::save()` will.

Comment: I updated it and tried it as you suggested, ndm, but still didn't work :(

Comment: Well, I didn't mean to say that this will fix your problem, just that only `save()` persists entities. You'll have to do some debugging, I'd start with checking whether an `UPDATE` query is being issued, and when it is being issued. Also try a different DBMS to check whether this is a Postgres specific problem.

Comment: Thanks @ndm! I'm at least 1 step further, but not quite working how I want it. Turns out the problem only occurs if I run this migration with other migrations. If I run it by itself, it works correctly. It seems as if the table description is getting cached somewhere, but I can't figure out how to clear that cache, even with what I have above. I've found this with `forceRefresh`, but I can't figure out how to execute it - http://api.cakephp.org/3.1/source-class-Cake.Database.Schema.CachedCollection.html#47-71

Comment: The problem may be that the schema is "cached" in memory, ie it's only being read from the file cache once per run, and that already happend in one of your other migrations. You could try adding the column to the schema using `$agencies->schema()->addColumn()` (**http://api.cakephp.org/3.1/class-Cake.Database.Schema.Table.html#_addColumn**), or create a method in your table class that re-initializes the schema with the `forceRefresh` option passed (**https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/3.1.4/src/ORM/Table.php#L420-L424**).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @ndm for figuring this out for me. I ended up having to update the table schema. I believe this is because the Migration table part updates the SQL, but doesn't update the Schema.

Here's the final code:

```
    // Clear the CakePHP Model cache
    Cache::clear(null, '_cake_model_');

    $table = $this->table('agencies');
    $table->addColumn('display_route_number', 'boolean', [
        'default' => true,
        'null' => false,
    ]);
    $table->update();

    $agencies = TableRegistry::get('Agencies');

    // REQUIRED!! Add the field to the Table schema
    $agencies->schema()->addColumn('display_route_number', [
        'type' => 'boolean',
        'default' => true,
        'null' => false
    ]);

    $agency = $agencies->find()
        ->where(['short_name' => 'bart'])
        ->first();
    // Items to update
    $agency->display_route_number = false;
    // And save it back to the DB
    $agencies->save($agency);
```